# The TINYINT UNSIGNED data column can't minus in where clause of MySQL_8 in MacOS

Tags: mysql, where-clause, tinyint

Here is the data in MySQL(8.0.x) running with MacOS:

```
ysql> desc t_room;
+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| roomNum      | varchar(60)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| roomType     | varchar(20)       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| roomDesc     | varchar(400)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rentPayDay   | tinyint unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rentFee      | smallint unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| asstMine     | varchar(400)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| asstOwner    | varchar(400)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| owner        | varchar(30)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| signDate     | date              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| contract     | mediumblob        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| roomFacility | varchar(120)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select rentPayDay from t_room;
+------------+
| rentPayDay |
+------------+
|         15 |
|         20 |
|         25 |
|         10 |
+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

when I do the query with where clause as below, everything is fine:

```
mysql> select roomNum, owner, rentPayDay from t_room where rentPayDay - 10 <= 5;
+---------------+--------+------------+
| roomNum       | owner  | rentPayDay |
+---------------+--------+------------+
| xxxC-906     | John   |         15 |
| xxxxx-908    | Doe   |         10 |
+---------------+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT, when I minus a value that maybe bigger than some of the rentPayDay values, like this:

```
mysql> select roomNum, owner, rentPayDay from t_room where rentPayDay - 11 <= 5;
```

things went wrong like this:

```
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`dev_learn`.`t_room`.`rentPayDay` - 11)'
```

Any one have any idea about this?   why the TINYINT data can't minus a bigger numeric value in the where clause?

Comment: `tinyint unsigned` means it can't contain negative (below 0) values. If your subtraction results in a negative value, it causes that error.

Comment: *`where rentPayDay - 11 <= 5`*

Use such conditions never. It forbids index usage and causes table fullscan.

When possible convert the condition expression to the form 

`{column} {operator} {constant expression}`

The expression will be evaluated during execution plan building - one time per the whole query.

I.e. the expression must look like

`where rentPayDay <= 5 + 11` Additionally - the problem with "out of range" will not occur.

Comment: @Akina answer show me the way to solve the problem.
May thanks to you and your reminds.

Comment: Reply @KenWhite, I didn't find any reference, but I guess the ```{rentPayDay - 11}``` express should follow the same restriction as rentPayDay's definition. 
the better and safe way should be compare rentPayDay with some other calculated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [`UNSIGNED TINYINT` has a range 0-255](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html), and negative values can't be expressed in it.

If you're getting casting errors, consider:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE CAST(rentPayDay AS DECIMAL) - 11 <= 5;
```

As [demonstrated here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/72MT8a6aC6MDtEHBiVURjA/0).

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem.
Many thanks to you.

Comment: Cannot solve. The substraction, not the function, is performed firstly. Due to operand type it is performed as unsigned calculation - and negative result causes error.

Comment: I've tried a new approach. Surprisingly annoying to fix.

Comment: @Akina show the right direction to this. my problem solved as this :
select roomNum, owner, rentPayDay
from t_room
where (rentPayDay >= EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW())) AND (rentPayDay <= EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW()) + 5);

Comment: That's another solution to avoid the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

with the reference of @Akina and @Ken White, here is my guess to this error:

```
the express {columnName OPERATOR -value-} still be restricted as a whole with the same definition of {columnName}.
```

I don't know why and what happened in MySQL'e response to my query.
The better way to solve this:

```
please refer to @Akina comment under my original question post.
```

Many thanks to all who care and help.